# difference Between two dates In dw script in mule

Tags: datetime, mule, dataweave

I am getting JSON request with one date field , my JSON request is( it always in this format only) :-

```
{
    MyDate:"28:00"
}
```

My requirement is, if the value is greater than 24 then subtract the value with 24 and return the result. Below is my logic I am implementing my DW Script ( I  am converting Json To XML)

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%var checkdate= "24:00"  as :datetime {format: "HH:mm"}

---
Logic:{

    FinalValue: payload.MyDate when payload.MyDate [0..1] <"24" otherwise (

                    FinalValue: (("payload.MyDate " as :datetime) - ( checkdate as :datetime)))

}
```

**Issue Is** :- My otherwise condition is not working for this above sample request my output should be

```
<Logic>
<FinalValue>04:00AM</FinalValue>
</Logic>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below logic for the input you have provided :-

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
Logic:{

    FinalValue: payload.MyDate when ((payload.MyDate[0..1] as :number)  < 24)
     otherwise  ((payload.MyDate[0..1] as :number) - 24) ++ (payload.MyDate[2..-1])

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support , let me check